# Integral of $\sqrt{a(b(x+c)^2+1)}/((x-1)x^{3/2})$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, radicals, rational-functions

I am trying to solve

$$\int_{x_0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{a(b(x+c)^2+1)}}{(x-1)x^{3/2}}dx$$

where, $a,b,c,x_0,x\in\Bbb R$ and $b,c,x>0$ and $x_0>1$.

I tried a $\sinh$ substitution without too much success. I also tried something like $v=\sqrt{a(b(x+c)^2+1)}\quad$, but maybe I should first do some more transformations before attempting something like that.

This is not homework. I would be grateful for some hints.

Comment: If $x_0 \leq 1$ the integral is divergent.

Comment: The primitive comes in terms of elliptic functions... I don't think you'll be able to get an expression with only "ususl" functions.

Comment: @Zacky I had a quick look at that case and it doesn't appear to be much simpler.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, I forgot to include that $x_0>1$. I got an answer full of Elliptic functions from Mathematica, but that is not useful to me. I guess I will have to try and play with it.

Comment: Does your integral converge on the given interval?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think so, yes.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi, don't bother playing with it... If you were able to get an answer not involving elliptic functions then you would have proved that elliptic functions can be written in closed form in terms of "usual" functions, which is not the case.

Comment: The indefinite integral leads to a Elliptic function.

Comment: @PierreCarre Thank you - sad times.